Does setting innerText or innerHTML from JavaScript trigger an input event?
Can updating an element inside that element's oninput handler trigger an infinite loop? I tested the following in Firefox. It does not trigger the event, but I want to know if I can expect all browsers to behave this way.
<html>
<body>
    <div id="editable" contenteditable="true">Original content</div>
    <script>
        const editableDiv = document.getElementById('editable');
        editableDiv.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
            // In Firefox, this does not trigger an infinite loop
            editableDiv.innerText += "!"
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

According to MDN (emphasis mine):

The input event fires when the value of an <input>, <select>, or <textarea> element has been changed as a direct result of a user action (such as typing in a textbox or checking a checkbox). The event also applies to elements with contenteditable enabled...

What exactly does "direct result of a user action* mean, and could it include setting the .innerText or .innerHTML of the element FROM an input handler? The UI Events spec is ambiguous.
Is this expected behavior explicitly describe somewhere?

W3 shows it as "e.g., keyboard input in an editable region, deleting or formatting text, ..."

Okay thanks all. For all practical purposes, these answer my questions. Still , I would love to know exactly what "direct user action" means, and where it is described in the spec. Everything I can find just gives examples.

The input event is designed to fire when the user makes a direct change to the element, such as typing in it or deleting content. This user-driven interaction is what is meant by "direct result of a user action." It typically does not include programmatic changes made via JavaScript (like setting innerText or innerHTML) since these are not direct user actions.
Most modern browsers should generally adhere to the spec and not trigger the input event for programmatic changes.
In a given browser, direct user interactions and programmatic changes are generally handled differently by the event system. for example:
When a user interacts with an element, browsers automatically trigger the associated events in the correct order. For example, typing in a text field triggers keydown, keypress, input, and keyup events.
When JavaScript changes an element's properties or content, browsers do not automatically trigger events unless explicitly instructed to do so with methods like dispatchEvent.
The issue is better discussed in this Question's answers.

This answer is verbose and vague. It sounds like it was written by AI. ex:  "Most modern browsers should generally adhere to the spec and not trigger the input event for programmatic changes." I'll accept an answer the links to the spec that describes exactly what "direct result of a user action" means.
